# Mysql query isn't working in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

ive been trying to retrive some messages sent by ser from a chat table. and i came up with a query which is working quite well in phpmyadmin.

but when i use the same query in laravel it isn't working.

```
SELECT user2,message,created_at FROM ( SELECT user2,message,created_at FROM chats WHERE user1 ='Tiffany' UNION SELECT user1,message,created_at FROM chats WHERE user2 ='Tiffany' in ( SELECT DISTINCT user2 FROM chats WHERE user1 ='Tiffany' UNION SELECT distinct user1 FROM chats WHERE user2 ='Tiffany' ) )tb2 WHERE user2 !='Tiffany' GROUP BY user2
```

ive tried almost everything but could find a solution. please give me a small explanation why the above query isn't working. the fields of my chat table are

id,user1(varchar),user2(varchar),message,created_at(timestamp),updated_at(timestamp)

the whole code ive used

```
    if ($pmessage = \DB::select('select user2,message,created_at
  from (select user2,message,created_at from chats where user1 ='Tiffany'
  union select user1,message,created_at from chats where user2 ='Tiffany'
  in ( select distinct user2 from chats where user1 ='Tiffany'
  union select distinct user1 from chats where user2 ='Tiffany' ))
  where user2 != 'Tiffany'
  group by user2')) {
      return response()->json(['pmessage' => $pmessage, 'status' => 200], 200);
  } else {
      return response()->json(['status' => 505], 505);
  }
```

Comment: Are you using DB:: or Eloquent? Post your code please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin  im using DB::  check the edited version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use DB::raw(). Something like:

```
$pmessage = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT ..."))
```

Also, you need to mix your quotes. So use double-quotes **around** your query, so that you can use single-quotes **within** your query. So you should be using something like this:

```
$pmessage = \DB::select( \DB::raw("Select user2,message,created_at
from (select user2,message,created_at from chats where user1 ='Tiffany'
union select user1,message,created_at from chats where user2 ='Tiffany'
in ( select distinct user2 from chats where user1 ='Tiffany'
union select distinct user1 from chats where user2 ='Tiffany' ))
where user2 != 'Tiffany'
group by user2')"));
```

Comment: i did that but its still not working ive used postman to check it and its giving an error

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current code? Maybe include the error you are getting from postman?

Comment: ive its already edited and the error im getting on postman is Status 500 Internal Server Error
500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

i root folder you have file .env after open with notepad you shold have command like this

**

```js
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=VTRcD5ZoIabuY9QR5Ih1QeCTTgCHQZrR

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=angulara
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

also you must corect config DB in config/database.php

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the configurations ive just typed a simple select query and it works. so im pretty sure that configurations are done properly.